# What is the math governing the shape of Inkscape's spiro paths?

Tags: inkscape, mathematics

I have begun experimenting with Inkscape's "spiro" mode for curves.  Since I usually end up writing Python to create art that Inkscape just doesn't have the tools to accomplish, I'm curious what the math behind the "spiro" curves is.

What formulas does Inkscape use to choose the Bézier handle points for Spiro paths?

Comment: Spiros are the result of [Raph Levien’s PhD thesis](http://www.levien.com/phd/thesis.pdf), which devotes an entire chapter to conversion to Bézier curves. I may summarise the respective parts in an answer if I find the time, but I won’t be angry, if anybody does so before me.

Comment: By the way as a question this is better suited for [computergraphics.SE](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I've been trying to get a grip on the PhD thesis.  One thing that has not yet become clear is how inkscape constrains the curves that travel through multiple points.  My first guess would be that it constrains the curvature to be continuous, but I can not yet rule out additional constraints.

Comment: What's wrong with proper quote marks?

Comment: It might be that inkscape is using Levien's spiro library (C and Java versions available) http://libspiro.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

The spiro path is costructed from [Euler spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral) segments, also known as *clothoids*, or *spiros*. Their identifying property is a linear change in curvature along their length.

The handles in Inkscape are (needlessly) ignored for spiro paths, and - instead using them as tangents - the smoothest path that goes through all the nodes is calculated and used. You can position the handles any way you like, but nothing about the curve will change.